# Count number of letters-numbers in an UTF8 string?

Tags: php

Basically I have this string for example `$str = 'По, своей 12'` I need something that returns the numbers of chars and numbers (leaving off spaces and other punctuation)

How can I achive this? Maybe doing a preg_replace with `\p{L}` and `[0-9]` ?

```
countChars('По, своей 12'); //> Should return: 9
```

Note: `mb_strlen()` counts spaces and punctuation too and i don't want this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it:

```
function countChars($haystack) {

    $count = preg_replace("/[^\p{L}0-9]/uim",'',$haystack);
    return mb_strlen($count);

}
```